# how to split terminal from bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal, gnu-screen

i would like to achieve this functionality from bash script . I want to create a multiple terminals and execute different scripts in each terminal.
Check this link for more details.
[how to get multiple terminals using screen command](http://tomlee.co/2011/10/gnu-screen-splitting/)

Screen command does the job, but what if how would i achieve this from bash script and run different commands in each terminal simultaneously as show below, where i want to split the screen in two regions and run top command in one terminal and take_backup script in another terminal.

```
#/bin/sh
screen_name1=$(screen_split vertically)
screeN_name2=$(screen_split_horizontally)
execute_command(top, screen_name1)
execute_command(take_backup, screen_name2)
```

I know terminator does this task, but i would like to achieve the above task without using terminator

any suggestions?

Comment: Please explain the functionality, don't expect people to follow a link, understand it, then come back and do something from scratch...

Comment: This should give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537149/how-to-start-tmux-with-several-windows-in-different-directories

Comment: i would like run this without any special pacakges as tmux, but i have screen installed in my machine

Comment: `screen` supports a similar configuration to `tmux` for starting multiple windows and programs. Just take a look at the *screenrc* configuration.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/49245/start-multiple-apps-running-in-shells-split-in-one-console this helped me a bit but its difficult to follow the man pages of screen http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen

Comment: What makes you believe bash supports this out-of-the-box?